# KeyListener not working using Applet

Tags: java, events, applet, keylistener

I have an applet using a keylistener, but the events are not triggered when I press the keys..
I also add the setFocusable(true), but didn't work too..

Here is my code

http://pastebin.com/WnFVVps7

I am creating a new KeyListener and adding it to the applet object.
Also I am using setFocusable(true) on my init() method.

I don't know what to do more, can someone take a look at my code? thanks.

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a while(true) with Thread sleep inside it. The keystrokes were not triggered because of that, I changed the code to start the while(true) inside a new Thread and works now :)

Thanks all for your patience ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is common issue with `KeyListener`.

The problem is, `KeyListener` will only respond to key strokes when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.  This, generally, makes it inappropriate for general use, it's really a specialised listener.

Instead, you should use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which allows you to control the focus level that the key strokes will be triggered at

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I got it solved when I changed the while(true) with a new thread running it. Thanks alot for your reply anyways ;)

Comment: Excsue me while I got out side and shoot myself.  You do realise that Swing is a single threaded environment and interactions with the UI should only be executed from within the context the EDT...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch global key events for the application instead of just for a component, use `KeyEventPostProcessor`. This should be used carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but maybe the problem is that you declare a class KeyListener and also import another class by that name. Try renaming your KeyListener-class to something less generic.

Also: Are you sure the class KeyListener should implement KeyAdapter and not java.awt.event.KeyListener?

Do KeyListener.keyReleased() and .keyTyped() work?

Comment: I renamed the class to just "key" , and also not working :s
I also implemented KeyListener instead of extending KeyAdapter and nothing :s

The other events don't get triggered also